# ARM bare-metal multi-core core selection

Tags: multithreading, arm, multicore, bare-metal

**For a multi-core ARM platform e.g. (Cortex-A53 cluster of 4 CPU's):**
**How** can we assign a specific core to run some function as a base for writing a simple bare scheduler? 
**How** do different mainline RTOS's implement such functionality on ARM?

Comment: what chip are you currently trying to do this on?

Answer (score 3):

Well assigning a single core to a software or multiple cores to a software is not a hardware configuration that can be changed. It all depends on the use case and how the software flow goes. Lets take an example.

Lets take CortexA53 cluster of 4 cores. Normally in the start a board initializing firmware runs. Like FSBL(First stage bootloader) in case of zcu102 by xilinx, it also has 4 cortexA53 cores. After that runs ATF (arm trusted firmware), after that runs uboot. All these run on core 0.

**Important**: Now when we launch any binary using u-boot, its launched on core0. Lets say we launched linux. Now after couple of initializations linux will start other cores using some Soc specific registers. Normally two registers are important. When software on one core wants to start the other core it will load the software in memory that it wants to execute on core1 and it will program a special register with its start address and using another special register it will bring it out of reset and core1 will start executing that software.

So you see it all depends on the software that it want to use other cores or not.

So write your code without any fear that it will get automatically executed by other cores and everything going bang!!!

One correction here, for simplicity I said above that linux directly uses registers to start other cores. It is not the case in ARM. We use special calls called SMC. These calls go to secure world where ATF looks into what arguments are passed for the SMC and does the appropriate service.

**Extra stuff:** To get started quickly use vendor provided startup files and write a simple hello world application by accessing its serial and load it using uboot by following command

```
fatload mmc 0:1 0x0 app.bin; go 0x0
```

it will load your application from the sd card and launch it on core0 at address 0x0.
Obviously you will have to change the address to the one that your application is linked to and also the partition number given after mmc.

Answer (score 2):

You are jumping ahead, first you need to see how the chip vendor manages those cores.  Falls into two major categories, one is the chip vendor releases resets on all the cores at once, the other is the chip vendor releases reset on one core and that core can then through CSRs release the reset on the other cores.  The raspberry pi family is an example of the former, allwinner based stuff is an example of the latter.

Its still very manageable though, the cores are all going to enter at the same place in memory, the reset exception address, so you either place code that sorts the cores from the beginning or as you release each core you change the reset handler somewhere to route each new core to a new place.  If you look at the raspberry pi baremetal forum you will see simple code that does this and/or just dump the code that the GPU bootloader places at the beginning of arm ram to sort the cores (boot without a config.txt which parks three of the cores and lets core0 run, then put some code in there so core0 can printout via the uart the contents of the first so many dozen words, disassemble that you can see how they do it).  Basically each core has a unique id that you can use to route that cores execution to its own code.

A ported OS should be doing all of this for you.

The early multi-cores was pretty obvious and shown in the technical reference manual that each core had its own clock enable and reset, up to the chip vendor to decide what to do with those.  The newer cores and documentation have this black box, so I dont know how that works, but do know that we see both flavors of solution among chip vendors.  I find the broadcom/pi approach better only because there arent hidden/undocumented CSRs to find or figure out, where allwinner you have to wait for someone to hack through that to figure it out.  Doesnt mean all broadcoms nor allwinners are the same, each company is free to design each individual part however they like and may very well have different solutions.  I wouldnt be surprised if broadcom's pi related parts have a control register that the GPU fiddles and that we might be able to fiddle ourselves if we could find it.

Once you get the cores running then it is a matter of simply pointing the program counter of a specific core to a specific address.  Either from reset you control where that core is, or through interrupts or exceptions to that core you then return control to a different address.  No difference from control over a single core processor.  There is no magic here.

Comment: Thanks for reply<br>it will be nice of you if you can elaborate the last paragraph more this point is exactly what I care much

Comment: I think I covered it, how do you guide/switch a single core from one thread to another?  How is this any different?  How it differs is you might (or might not depending on your design) have to read a register to determine which thread is running that code to determine which thread you want to switch it to.

Comment: There is no magic here all the cores see the same memory space so they all (can) see the same code.  Instead of simply switching a core from one thread to the next thread that is in priority order, you can instead have multiple threads going and each core may or may not have its own next thread.  Or not you could just have whatever core comes next takes the next thread in priority order.

Comment: Understand that unlike single core, these cores are truly running in parallel, so any data structures or paths that require them to go through in single file order requires some work you wouldnt normally have to deal with.  One solution for example would be having each core have its own sets of threads, core0 switches through one set, core1 a different set, then they dont have to go through the task switching code single file, they can run through that in parallel.  basically serialize the code and data or parallel the code and data.